# Formula Field on Log a Call Global Action Layout

Tags: formula-field, log-a-call

I want to add an image to the Log a Call layout to represent how the call went. I've created a custom picklist field and then a custom formula field on the Actions object. However, when I open the Log a Call layout from Global Actions, the formula field does not appear in the available field section. Are formula fields not supported in Global Action Layouts? If so, is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have also come across the same issue - where I had a formula field that I could not add to the Global Actions page layout.

The alternative I found was to create a screen flow instead.